# interpolate/extrapolate missing dates in python?

Tags: python, pandas, scipy, interpolation, extrapolation

lets say i have the following dataframe

```
bb = pd.DataFrame(data = {'date' :['','','','2015-09-02', '2015-09-02', '2015-09-03','','2015-09-08', '', '2015-09-11','2015-09-14','','' ]})     
bb['date'] = pd.to_datetime(bb['date'], format="%Y-%m-%d")
```

I want to interpolate and exptrapolate linearly to fill the missing date values . I used the following code but it doesn't change anything. I am new to pandas. please help

```
bb= bb.interpolate(method='time')
```

Comment: how do you want to interpolate. Do you want to fill up all the missing dates or just those blank spaces?

Comment: I want to interpolate linearly, Thanks

Comment: @Eular dates should be interpolated linearly. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To extrapolate you have to use `bfill()` and `ffill()`. Missing values will be assigned by back- (or forward) values.

To linear interpolate you have to use function `interpolate` but dates need to convert to numbers:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

bb = pd.DataFrame(data = {'date' :['','','','2015-09-02', '2015-09-02', '2015-09-03','','2015-09-08', '', '2015-09-11','2015-09-14','','' ]})     
bb['date'] = pd.to_datetime(bb['date'], format="%Y-%m-%d")     

# convert to seconds
tmp = bb['date'].apply(lambda t: (t-datetime(1970,1,1)).total_seconds())
# linear interpolation
tmp.interpolate(inplace=True)    
# back convert to dates
bb['date'] = pd.to_datetime(tmp, unit='s') 
bb['date'] = bb['date'].apply(lambda t: t.date())
# extrapolation for the first missing values
bb.bfill(inplace='True')

print bb
```

Result:

```
         date
0  2015-09-02
1  2015-09-02
2  2015-09-02
3  2015-09-02
4  2015-09-02
5  2015-09-03
6  2015-09-05
7  2015-09-08
8  2015-09-09
9  2015-09-11
10 2015-09-14
11 2015-09-14
12 2015-09-14
```

Comment: thanks @Stanley, but in the row 7 can't the value be 2015-09-09?

Comment: No, you have to put such behavior to code. Look to changes in code above.